# ASP.NET Core 1.1 getting all users and their roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am new to .NET trying to get a list of all the registered user along with their role names and send them to a view using a viewModel.

Here's the ViewModel:

```
public class ApplicationUserListViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "User Email Address")]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    public  List<IdentityUserRole<string>> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I tried this for getting all users along with their roles and make a ViewModel for each user and put all the view models in a list to pass to the View:

```
var users =  _userManager.Users.ToList();
var userList = users.Select(u => 
                new ApplicationUserListViewModel {
                    UserEmail = u.Email,
                    Roles = u.Roles.ToList() }
                    ).ToList();
```

But this always gives me 0 roles count for every user when I clearly have roles assigned to every user.

Comment: `_userManager.Users.Include(u => u.Roles)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You anwsered yourself but your solution is not perfect because it causes performance issue. You're executing one request to your database to query users then in your `foreach` loop you execute a new query for each user to get their related roles which is really bad. If you've X user in your database you will end up using :

- One query to get users
- X queries to get each user's roles.

You can do better by including the related roles in one query like this:

```
foreach (var user in _userManager.Users.Include(u => u.Roles).ToList())
{              
    list.Add(new ApplicationUserListViewModel {
        UserEmail = user.Email,
        Roles = user.Roles
    });
}
```

Or just this:

```
var users = _userManager.Users.Include(u => u.Roles)
                        .Select(u => new ApplicationUserListViewModel {
                            UserEmail = user.Email,
                            Roles = user.Roles
                        })
                        .ToList();
```

---

### Update for ASP.NET Core Identity 2.x

This solution is not valid for ASP.NET Core Identity 2.x as `IdentityUser` no longer contains a `Roles` property. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51005445/5392786) for ASP.NET Core Identity 2.x.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I got this working. This is probably not how it should be done but it works fine.

```
var list = new List<ApplicationUserListViewModel>();

foreach (var user in _userManager.Users.ToList())
{              
    list.Add(new ApplicationUserListViewModel() {
        UserEmail = user.Email,
        Roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)
    });
}
```